# strategy/matrix in classic editor

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following code snippet in my Azure DevOps yaml file. How can I convert this structure into a classic editor based pipeline? Is it possible to do this through [multipliers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)?

```
  strategy:
    matrix:
      LOAD:
        systemTestCategoryName: LOAD
        AgentName: Agent1
        NUNIT_INCLUDE_CATEGORIES: LoadTest
      API:
        systemTestCategoryName: API
        AgentName: Agent2
        NUNIT_INCLUDE_CATEGORIES: API
      CHROME:
        systemTestCategoryName: UI_CHROME
        AgentName: Agent3
        NUNIT_INCLUDE_CATEGORIES: CHROME
      FIREFOX:
        systemTestCategoryName: UI_FIREFOX
        AgentName: Agent4
        NUNIT_INCLUDE_CATEGORIES: GUI

  pool:
    name: mypool
    demands:
      agent.name -equals $(AgentName)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Definitely not in the same way you're doing it in YAML. Multipliers are the closest you're going to get, though.

Multipliers are going to run every combination of the values being multiplied, which isn't what you want. You could try something extra hacky like making a variable called `Configurations` with the value `FIREFOX,CHROME,ETC`, multiply on that, and then have variables called `FIREFOX`, `CHROME`, and `ETC` with a JSON string containing the actual variables values, then use an inline script to retrieve the correct variable, parse it, and then use those values.

But that's definitely not going to work with the agent demand; you'd have to get rid of that and make sure that the tests can run independently of each other on any agent.

Probably the easiest approach is first take care of the agent requirement as stated above, and then unify all of these variables to be a single common value, then multiply on that. So instead of

```
  FIREFOX:
    systemTestCategoryName: UI_FIREFOX
    AgentName: Agent4
    NUNIT_INCLUDE_CATEGORIES: GUI
```

You'd have

```
  FIREFOX:
    systemTestCategoryName: FIREFOX
    NUNIT_INCLUDE_CATEGORIES: FIREFOX
```

which can then be collapsed into a single multiplied variable that contains `FIREFOX,CHROME,ETC`.

You could also skip multipliers entirely and just have 4 separate jobs that share a common task group.